# How to pass a variable to a class __init__ method automatically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, object

I am making a game in python and an object in pygame, the display surface, is needed to draw anything to the screen. This object needs to be referenced in all of my classes in separate files. Right now, every `__init__()` method of all the classes requires the surface object to be manually added in the parameters. It gets tedious and makes the code messier, is there a better way to share a specific object between classes in separate files?

Comment: Can you provide some example code?

Comment: "Explicit is better than implicit" (according to `import this`).

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this, the most naive probably being a global object.  Probably the best way to deal with it though, is by having the display surface (and anything else which is used widely within your project) in a module you import.  Make a new folder 'Screen' with a file __init__.py in it.

in __init__.py put the following:

```
screen = screenObject()
```

Then in any file you need the screen object you can just:

```
from Screen import screen
```

Then just use screen as your object wherever you need it.  Modules in python are run the first time they are loaded and otherwise shared, so this screen object will be the same one wherever you use it.

Answer (score 0):

A one simple way to do it would be use a class attribute and provide a class method to set it.

```
class Class:
    surface = None

    @classmethod
    def set_surface(cls, surface):
        cls.surface = surface

    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, arg3):
        print('surface: {}'.format(self.surface))

c1 = Class(1, 2, 3)  # -> surface: None
Class.set_surface(42)
c2 = Class(1, 2, 3)  # -> surface: 42
```